# Cant display jpeg images on a SSRS Report (CRM Dynamics Online)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, jpeg, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm trying to display jpeg images on an SSRS Report. The images are stored in attachments within a notes section. Png images display both on visual studio and when I run the report on CRM. Jpeg only seems to run on Visual Studio and not when i run on it on CRM Online 2016.

I have tried every solution under the sun and i still have no idea how to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**PREVIEW ON VISUAL STUDIO 2012**
[image]

**IMAGE PROPERTIES**
[image]

**PREVIEW ON CRM DYNAMICS ONLINE 2016**
[image]

**PREVIEW ON CRM DYNAMICS ONLINE 2016 SOURCE**
[image]

Comment: If you inspect the webpage, where does the image link attempt to direct to? If you navigate to that link can you find the image? Is there any difference between browsers. The attachments are Base64 encoded, are you decoding them?

Comment: Hi James, I have added extra info to my post. I have tried converting the document body using this: =System.Convert.FromBase64String(Fields!documentbody.Value) but it still doesnt work.

Comment: the same problem happened to me. The attached Images to the Notes are not appearing in the SSRS Report.